# Как при увеличении одного блока сделать так чтобы он не толкал другой блок

Tags: css, css3

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы при увеличении одного блока он не толкал другой блок без использования `position: absolute`?
Как видите я тут поставил еще `margin-top: 200px`, но он всё равно толкает вниз `h1`.

У меня такая ситуация, что в верстке увеличивается целый блок громадный, а ему `position: absolute` нельзя задать. Рассматриваются любые другие варианты.

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
}

img:hover {
  width: 200px;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-block">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tfMV.png">
</div>
<div class="another-element">
  <h1>another element</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно с помощью `transform: scale(n);`

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: 0 0 0;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-block">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tfMV.png">
</div>
<div class="another-element">
  <h1>another element</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: ваш вариант более изящный принимаю его

Comment: Пожалуйста ^_^.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно что вам нужно. Но как вариант, можете задать:

```
.img-block{
  max-height:100px;
}
```

Тогда картинка будет просто наезжать.

Comment: нужно чтобы один блок не толкал при увеличении другова что тут не понятного.Спасибо за ответ то что нужно